# Plot list of lists in histogram - x and y values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of lists:

```
[[Decimal('3.69578'), Decimal('5.12519')], [Decimal('3.69586'),Decimal('2.50457468')], [Decimal('3.69587'), Decimal('72.33894358')], [Decimal('3.69629'), Decimal('54.2359599')], ...]
```

and I would like to plot it in a histogram with matplotlib using one of the values in the sub-lists for the x axis and the other one for the y axis.

```
plt.hist(list)
```

gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2896, in hist
stacked=stacked, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5652, in hist
    m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i], **hist_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 176, in histogram
    mn, mx = [mi+0.0 for mi in range]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could plot them as floats with

```
plt.hist([[float(x) for x in y] for y in list])
```

Comment: Returns this: ([array([ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), array([ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), ... , array([  1.00000000e-01,   1.19370304e+02,   2.38640608e+02,
         3.57910912e+02,   4.77181216e+02,   5.96451520e+02,
         7.15721823e+02,   8.34992127e+02,   9.54262431e+02,
         1.07353274e+03,   1.19280304e+03]), <a list of 53 Lists of Patches objects>)